# Elasticsearch check if fieldA has value x then search fieldB for term xyz

Tags: php, laravel, elasticsearch

Suppose I have stored bellow data and want to search for term `xy` in `old_value` and `new_value` fields of those documents that their `field_name` is `curriculum_name_en` or `curriculum_name_pr`:

```
{
   "took": 1,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
       "total": 5,
       "successful": 5,
       "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 98,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
        {
           "_index": "my_index",
           "_type": "audit_field",
           "_id": "57526c197e83c",
           "_score": 1,
           "_source": {
              "session_id": 119,
              "trans_seq_no": 1,
              "table_seq_no": 1,
              "field_id": 2,
              "field_name": "curriculum_id",
              "new_value": 118,
              "old_value": null
           }
        },
        {
           "_index": "my_index",
           "_type": "audit_field",
           "_id": "57526c197f2c3",
           "_score": 1,
           "_source": {
               "session_id": 119,
               "trans_seq_no": 1,
               "table_seq_no": 1,
               "field_id": 3,
               "field_name": "curriculum_name_en",
               "new_value": "Test Index creation",
               "old_value": null
           }
        },
        {
           "_index": "my_index",
           "_type": "audit_field",
           "_id": "57526c198045c",
           "_score": 1,
           "_source": {
               "session_id": 119,
               "trans_seq_no": 1,
               "table_seq_no": 1,
               "field_id": 4,
               "field_name": "curriculum_name_pr",
               "new_value": null,
               "old_value": null
           }
        },
        {
           "_index": "my_index",
           "_type": "audit_field",
           "_id": "57526c1981512",
           "_score": 1,
           "_source": {
              "session_id": 119,
              "trans_seq_no": 1,
              "table_seq_no": 1,
              "field_id": 5,
              "field_name": "curriculum_name_pa",
              "new_value": null,
              "old_value": null
           }
        }      
        ]
      }
   }
```

and many more fields may be there, now user may select one or more of those fields and define a search term across those fields that he/she selected, the challenge is here, how we can say elastic that consider `field_name` to match those fields that user selected, then search in `old_value`, and `new_value`.
for example if user select `curriculum_name_en` and `curriculum_name_pr` and then want to search for `xy` inside `old_value` and `new_value` fields of those documents that their `field_name` is above fields.
how we can do that?

Answer (score 1):

The idea with this requirement is that you need to make something like: *the query needs to match `new_value` and/or `old_value` only if `field_name` matches a certain value as well*. There is no programmatic-like way of saying *if this then that*.

What I'm suggesting is something like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "field_name": [
              "curriculum_name_en",
              "curriculum_name_pr"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "Test Index",
            "fields": ["new_value","old_value"]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

So, your *if this then that* condition is a `must` statement from a `bool` query where your *if* and *then* branches live inside the `must`.

Answer (score 0):

This may solve your problem

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "and": [
          {
             "query" : {
               "terms" : {
                 "field_name" : [
                   "curriculum_name_en",
                   "curriculum_name_pr"
                 ],
                 "minimum_match" : 1
               }
             }
           },
           {
             "query" : {
                "terms" : {
                   "new_value" : [
                      "test", "index"  
                   ],
                   "minimum_match" : 1
                }
             }
           }
         ]
       }
     }
   }
 } 
}
```